# Chrome silently embedded in desktop application, and that can save files locally via Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, wxpython

Is it possible to have a Python application with a GUI (such as TkInter or WxPython) with :

- a Chrome browser as a widget using the main part of the GUI, displaying a certain .html page
- **be able to save files locally thanks to Javascript that is run in the embedded Chrome** (that is normally impossible with any browser for security reasons)

If it's not possible in Python, I'm open to use another language (C++, etc.).

[image]

Comment: Chrome [allegedly supports](http://caniuse.com/filesystem) the [FileWriter API](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-writer-api-20120417/) although the API appears to be deprecated. It would be more useful to describe in more abstract terms what you're trying to achieve. See also: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Aya : it would be quite long to describe. I have started this project 2 years ago : http://www.bigpicture.bi/demo / https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js/ . Now I want to bundle it as a standalone software. In order to be able to reuse this JS library I spent months working on, I need to bundle a browser in a .exe + allow to save file locally from JS.

Comment: There's a project [here](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) which supposedly allows embedding Chrome into a variety of popular Python GUI libs. Saving stuff via JS will be problematic, but the CEF API may provide a way to pull the data directly from the underlying JS VM,  allowing you to use a native save dialog instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention that you're open to trying platforms other than Python. Have you seen Electron? It's a framework and runtime for building desktop applications in JavaScript with full access to the file system made by GitHub. It's based on Chromium, the same open source project that Chrome is based on.

- http://electron.atom.io
- http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/file-object/

Comment: Wonderful! It's exactly what I wanted, before having time to dream about it :) Pack CSS+HTML+JS into a standalone cross platform software ! Brilliant !

Comment: Here is the result @Nicko thanks to the use of Electron :) https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture-editor It's a standalone version of http://bigpicture.bi/demo. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be doable.  In current versions of wxPython there is the `wx.html2` module, which provides classes for embedding a fully featured browser in a wx window.  It's not Chrome itself, but probably close enough. See https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html

For your task you can probably have the javascript trigger an action which is caught by event handlers in the application GUI code, which will then save the files or do whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks @RobinDunn for these informations. It seems ([according to this](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html2.WebView.html)) that it's going to be InternetExplorer for Windows 7 platform :(  Is there a way to really force Chrome (or at least Firefox) ?

Comment: Not currently.  There was talk at one point of making Chromium available as one of the backend options, but I don't think that has gone very far yet.